# Kubernetes Calico node 'XXXXXXXXXXX' already using IPv4 Address XXXXXXXXX, CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, calico

I used the AWS Kubernetes Quickstart to create a Kubernetes cluster in a VPC and private subnet: https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-heptio/doc/heptio-kubernetes-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf. It was running fine for a while. I have Calico installed on my Kubernetes cluster. I have two nodes and a master. The calico pods on the master are running fine, the ones on the nodes are in crashloopbackoff state:

```
NAME                                                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-etcd-ztwjj                                                  1/1       Running            1          55d
calico-kube-controllers-685755779f-ftm92                           1/1       Running            2          55d
calico-node-gkjgl                                                  1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   270        22h
calico-node-jxkvx                                                  2/2       Running            4          55d
calico-node-mxhc5                                                  1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   9          25m
```

Describing one of the crashed pods:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-133:~$ kubectl describe pod calico-node-gkjgl -n kube-system
Name:           calico-node-gkjgl
Namespace:      kube-system
Node:           ip-10-0-0-237.us-east-2.compute.internal/10.0.0.237
Start Time:     Mon, 17 Sep 2018 16:56:41 +0000
Labels:         controller-revision-hash=185957727
                k8s-app=calico-node
                pod-template-generation=1
Annotations:    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod=
Status:         Running
IP:             10.0.0.237
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/calico-node
Containers:
  calico-node:
    Container ID:   docker://d89979ba963c33470139fd2093a5427b13c6d44f4c6bb546c9acdb1a63cd4f28
    Image:          quay.io/calico/node:v3.1.1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://quay.io/calico/node@sha256:19fdccdd4a90c4eb0301b280b50389a56e737e2349828d06c7ab397311638d29
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 18 Sep 2018 15:14:44 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 18 Sep 2018 15:14:44 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  270
    Requests:
      cpu:      250m
    Liveness:   http-get http://:9099/liveness delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  http-get http://:9099/readiness delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS:                     <set to the key 'etcd_endpoints' of config map 'calico-config'>  Optional: false
      CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND:          <set to the key 'calico_backend' of config map 'calico-config'>  Optional: false
      CLUSTER_TYPE:                       kubeadm,bgp
      CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING:        true
      CALICO_K8S_NODE_REF:                 (v1:spec.nodeName)
      FELIX_DEFAULTENDPOINTTOHOSTACTION:  ACCEPT
      CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR:               192.168.0.0/16
      CALICO_IPV4POOL_IPIP:               Always
      FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT:                  false
      FELIX_IPINIPMTU:                    1440
      FELIX_LOGSEVERITYSCREEN:            info
      IP:                                 autodetect
      FELIX_HEALTHENABLED:                true
    Mounts:
      /lib/modules from lib-modules (ro)
      /var/lib/calico from var-lib-calico (rw)
      /var/run/calico from var-run-calico (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from calico-cni-plugin-token-b7sfl (ro)
  install-cni:
    Container ID:  docker://b37e0ec7eba690473a4999a31d9f766f7adfa65f800a7b2dc8e23ead7520252d
    Image:         quay.io/calico/cni:v3.1.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/calico/cni@sha256:dc345458d136ad9b4d01864705895e26692d2356de5c96197abff0030bf033eb
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /install-cni.sh
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 17 Sep 2018 17:11:52 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 17 Sep 2018 16:56:43 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 17 Sep 2018 17:10:53 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:
      CNI_CONF_NAME:       10-calico.conflist
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS:      <set to the key 'etcd_endpoints' of config map 'calico-config'>      Optional: false
      CNI_NETWORK_CONFIG:  <set to the key 'cni_network_config' of config map 'calico-config'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /host/etc/cni/net.d from cni-net-dir (rw)
      /host/opt/cni/bin from cni-bin-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from calico-cni-plugin-token-b7sfl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  lib-modules:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:
  var-run-calico:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/run/calico
    HostPathType:
  var-lib-calico:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/calico
    HostPathType:
  cni-bin-dir:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/cni/bin
    HostPathType:
  cni-net-dir:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/cni/net.d
    HostPathType:
  calico-cni-plugin-token-b7sfl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  calico-cni-plugin-token-b7sfl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     :NoSchedule
                 :NoExecute
                 :NoSchedule
                 :NoExecute
                 CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                  From                                               Message
  ----     ------   ----                 ----                                               -------
  Warning  BackOff  4m (x6072 over 22h)  kubelet, ip-10-0-0-237.us-east-2.compute.internal  Back-off restarting failed container
```

The logs for the same pod:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-133:~$ kubectl logs calico-node-gkjgl -n kube-system -c calico-node
2018-09-18 15:14:44.605 [INFO][8] startup.go 251: Early log level set to info
2018-09-18 15:14:44.605 [INFO][8] startup.go 269: Using stored node name from /var/lib/calico/nodename
2018-09-18 15:14:44.605 [INFO][8] startup.go 279: Determined node name: ip-10-0-0-237.us-east-2.compute.internal
2018-09-18 15:14:44.609 [INFO][8] startup.go 101: Skipping datastore connection test
2018-09-18 15:14:44.610 [INFO][8] startup.go 352: Building new node resource Name="ip-10-0-0-237.us-east-2.compute.internal"
2018-09-18 15:14:44.610 [INFO][8] startup.go 367: Initialize BGP data
2018-09-18 15:14:44.614 [INFO][8] startup.go 564: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface ens3: 10.0.0.237/19
2018-09-18 15:14:44.614 [INFO][8] startup.go 432: Node IPv4 changed, will check for conflicts
2018-09-18 15:14:44.618 [WARNING][8] startup.go 861: Calico node 'ip-10-0-0-237' is already using the IPv4 address 10.0.0.237.
2018-09-18 15:14:44.618 [WARNING][8] startup.go 1058: Terminating
Calico node failed to start
```

So it seems like there is a conflict finding the node IP address, or Calico seems to think the IP is already assigned to another node. Doing a quick search i found this thread: https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/1628. I see that this should be resolved by setting the IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD to can-reach=DESTINATION, which I'm assuming would be "can-reach=10.0.0.237". This config is an environment variable set on calico/node container. I have been attempting to shell into the container itself, but kubectl tells me the container is not found:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-133:~$ kubectl exec calico-node-gkjgl --stdin --tty /bin/sh -c calico-node -n kube-system
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("calico-node")
```

I'm suspecting this is due to Calico being unable to assign IPs. So I logged onto the host and attempt to shell on the container using docker:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-237:~# docker exec -it k8s_POD_calico-node-gkjgl_kube-system_a6998e98-ba9a-11e8-a9fa-0a97f5a48ef4_1 /bin/bash
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"
```

So I guess there is no shell to execute in the container. Makes sense why Kubernetes couldn't execute that. I tried running commands externally to list environment variables, but I haven't been able to find any, I could be running these commands wrong however:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-237:~# docker inspect -f '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}}{{$value}} {{end}}' k8s_POD_calico-node-gkjgl_kube-system_a6998e98-ba9a-11e8-a9fa-0a97f5a48ef4_1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

root@ip-10-0-0-237:~# docker exec -it k8s_POD_calico-node-gkjgl_kube-system_a6998e98-ba9a-11e8-a9fa-0a97f5a48ef4_1 printenv IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"printenv\": executable file not found in $PATH"

root@ip-10-0-0-237:~# docker exec -it k8s_POD_calico-node-gkjgl_kube-system_a6998e98-ba9a-11e8-a9fa-0a97f5a48ef4_1 /bin/env
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/env\": stat /bin/env: no such file or directory"
```

Okay, so maybe I am going about this the wrong way. Should I attempt to change the Calico config files using Kubernetes and redeploy it? Where can I find these on my system? I haven't been able to find where to set the environment variables.

Comment: Depending on the linux distro used. It could sh shell. try /bin/sh

Comment: On second read, guess you are trying ton login to a container that is not yet running. Check https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8838#issuecomment-117284347 . See if you have the config file generated, try updating there and start the same again. Also I looked calico documentation, there is a way to set interfaces too interface=<IFACE NAME REGEX LIST>
                             Use the first valid IP address found on interfaces
                             named as per the first matching supplied interface 
        name regex. Regexes are separated by commas
        (e.g. eth.*,enp0s.*).

Comment: @Narain you are correct that the container was not running, and the comment you posted was very helpful for reference. Unfortunately I couldn't find the IP Detection Method in the /var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/config.json for the containers but I was able to get Calico running again by upgrading to v3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Calico docs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/reference/node/configuration) `IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD` is already defaulting to `first-round`.

My guess is that something or the IP address is not being released by the previous 'run' of calico, or just simply a bug in the `v3.1.1` version of calico.

Try:

1. Delete your Calico pods that are in a CrashBackOff loop

   ```
   kubectl -n kube-system delete calico-node-gkjgl calico-node-mxhc5
   ```

   Your pods will be re-created and hopefully initialize.
2. Upgrade Calico to `v3.1.3` or latest. Follow these [docs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/getting-started/kubernetes/upgrade/upgrade#upgrading-an-installation-that-uses-an-etcd-datastore) My guess is that Heptio's Calico installation is using the etcd datastore.
3. Try to understand how Heptio's AWS AMIs work and see if there are any issues with them. This might take some time so you could contact their support as well.
4. Try a different method to install Kubernetes with Calico. Well documented on https://kubernetes.io

Comment: I think you are correct that it was due to a bug. I had tried deleting the pods so they would restart but they soon after crashed. In the end I simply deleted the old deployment using kubectl delete deployment <calico-deployment-name> -n kubesystem, and following the instructions you listed in step 2 upgraded to v3.2.1. I created the new RBAC and installed the new deployment using kubectl apply -f <manifest-file-name>. After a few minutes the Calico pods started up successfully, along with the other containers in the cluster that were having issues running/restarting!

Comment: Awesome to hear!

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was to remove left over docker-networks on the Nodes.
I had to list out current networks on each Node: `docker network list` and then remove the unneeded ones: `docker network rm <networkName>`.
After doing that the calico deployment pods were running fine

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of the problem after debugging it and resolving it. Besides Kubernetes, I had other services running on the cluster (for example, `Clickhouse`, which was using `docker-compose`). This caused a problem with the network of the cluster.

According to the `docker network ls` command, there are the following networks on the Docker:

```bash
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
39c36916cc71   bridge           bridge    local
b90b28ce31ec   docker_default   bridge    local
f045c30c679f   host             host      local
36aa4115b540   none             null      local
```

I simply remove the container that what created by `docker-compose` and then run `docker network prune` command. It deletes `docker_default` network in my case or if you know which network to remove you can do it by executing `docker network rm <network-id>` command